# DateTime.now or Time.now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timezone

Which of the two should I be using in my Rails application:

```
DateTime.now or Time.now
```

Is there any harm in using both in the application?

Can there ever be any differences between the two in case of the above (`now`) example? (On my current system they are both showing the same time)

Comment: ActiveRecord and other ORMs like DateTime and Date for their database records. I think that's because Date has a greater range than Time. Time is based on the OS's notions of time, and, if I remember, has better integration with timezone information. You might want to look at [`home_run`](https://github.com/jeremyevans/home_run) as an alternative that is supposed to be a lot faster.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In reference to `Time.now` (not `DateTime.now`):

The object created will be created using the resolution available on your system clock, and so may include fractional seconds.

```
a = Time.new      #=> Wed Apr 09 08:56:03 CDT 2003
b = Time.new      #=> Wed Apr 09 08:56:03 CDT 2003
a == b            #=> false
"%.6f" % a.to_f   #=> "1049896563.230740"
"%.6f" % b.to_f   #=> "1049896563.231466"
```

Comment: Yes, fractional seconds can look bad if you don't expect them, but then can be truncated if you want by converting to an integer value for the seconds, or by using `strftime` to format them out while maintaining them for any timestamp math.

Comment: I'm working with Rails 3 and DateTime has fractional seconds as well. Is this difference only present in Rails 2?

Answer (score 59):

Use **`(Date)Time.current`** instead of  **`(Date)Time.now`**

Rails extends the `Time` and `DateTime` objects, and includes the `current` property for retrieving the time the Rails environment is set to (default = UTC), as opposed to the server time (Could be anything).

This is critical- You should always be working in UTC time except when converting between timezones for user input or display- but many production systems are *not* UTC by default. (e.g. Heroku is set to PST (GMT -8))

See article [**here**](https://web.archive.org/web/20130622051657/http://forrst.com/posts/Date_Time_current_vs_Date_Time_now_especially-RX1)

Comment: @user2503775 - Yes you could use that, but if for *some reason* you did want to work in a non-UTC timezone (which I think is never a good idea), at least you would be able to make the change by switching an environment variable instead of having to change a bunch of values in code.

Comment: @Yarin use Time.zone.now instead of Time.current instead of Time.now

Comment: @ajahongir Time.current returns Time.zone.now if zone it set, if not, then returns Time.now

Comment: `current` does help avoid writing `Time.now.zone` , but it does *not* solve the issue with potential fractional seconds added, as the answer by @slandau points out.

Comment: My understanding was that active record always converts the datetime into UTC before storing it into a datetime field.  As such isn't the best policy to just work in the current timezone and let rails magic do those conversions behind the scenes?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get the time in the application's time zone, you'll need to call `Time.zone.now`, so that's what I generally use.

`Time.now` and `DateTime.now` will both return a time in the system's time, which often is set to UTC.

Comment: Alternatively use (Date)[Time.current](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ffc273577a795bb41068bfc2a1bb575ec51a9712/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb#L29) as suggested by Yarin. Time.current will return Time.zone.now if Time.zone is set else returns Time.now.